# Decomposition of an integer into a sum of strictly positive integers

Tags: integer, ocaml, partition, decomposition

I have to write a function in OCaml `partitions: int -> int` that calculates the number of ways to write a strictly positive integer `n` as the sum of strictly positive integers.
I managed to write a function that returns the number of ways to write `n` as the sum of `k` integers, but I can't do it for all `k`.
Here is my code :

```
let rec partition n k =
match k with
    | k when k > n -> 0
    | k when k = n -> 1
    | 1 -> 1
    | _ -> (partition (n-1) (k-1)) + (partition (n-k) k);;

let partitions n = 
let result = 0 in 
for i = 1 to n do result = result + i done; result;;
```

My function `partition n k` is working but my function `partitions n` (the one that I must do) isn't...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try with this for you partitions function:

```ml
let partitions n = 
let result = ref 0 in 
for i = 1 to n do result := !result + (partition n i) done; !result;;
```

I replaced result with a ref to be able to change its value, and then I summed the number of partition for each i from 1 to n, for n, and return this sum

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answer. I've tried this for my partitions function but no matter what integer n I choose, I get the error "Out_of_memory". Maybe my gait wasn't the right one...

Comment: (For what it's worth, it's not particularly helpful to anyone if you just write parts of their homework for them with no discussion or explanation.)

Answer (score 0):

I note that the first call in the loop of the `partitions` function provided by @NathanFallet is for `k = 0`. You might work through the code to see what happens when `k = 0`.

(Hint: your `partition` function doesn't work for this case. That's fairly reasonable since you can't achieve a positive sum by adding together 0 numbers.)

Comment: You’re right, then it could be better to start with k = 1